# 7 day ban from reviews for approving "obvious spam?"

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I really don't recall approving spam, and I typically try to make good judgment calls when conducting the reviews, I don't just go through blindly accepting things and I certainly don't recall any spam.

Is there a way I can go back through my history to see what this is in reference to after it's been deleted? I'm provided a link to the review (which seems pointless as it was since taken down because it is "obvious spam" after all). This doesn't help me see what I did wrong or how that post was spam.

The link (for those who can see it): 
https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6319851

Comment: Yes, if a moderator caught you at missing obvious spam or vandalism in the review queue, you'll get a manual ban.

Comment: Can you please provide that link to us? 10k+ users and moderators can still see the post, so we can help you figure out what you missed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I edited to provide the link, thanks for the info.

Comment: The question itself is off-topic and thus should be closed and deleted...

Comment: Incidentally, the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221158/mp3-to-aac-flac-to-aac-conversion-encoding-net) on which the answer was posted needs to be closed.

Comment: Yes, obvious spam. http://i.stack.imgur.com/JJNbs.png

Comment: Though I suppose it does also answer the question. The obvious spam nature is partially obvious as it bumps a question from 2011.

Comment: @MartinSmith That looks like a reasonable answer to me? This question wasn't very strong, but was specific and the answer was specific about tools that would help. The tool was owned by a company, but I'm confident that Apple hasn't stooped to online spam advertising tactics so I don't think that's "spam."

Comment: The link is to some product by a company called "faasoft", not apple.

Comment: The only content in the answer was "you can use iTunes (programmatically, for 10m files? I don't think so), and here's an external link (potential spam)". Can't say if the spam was _obvious_ without seeing the target of the link, but that's very obviously not an acceptable answer.

Comment: I don't use iTunes so I wouldn't know what capabilities it has for changing audio files form one format to another. Perhaps I should have visited the link, but the content of the answer didn't seem out of context.

Comment: I digress. I suppose it is spam, but I'll argue for the sake of my reputation that it wasn't that "obvious." The answer does answer the question to anybody not clicking all the links. Lesson learned.

Comment: @leigero: at which point you should have *skipped* the post. By stating it 'looked good' you basically vetted the post as fine, which it wasn't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters A 7 day ban seems awfully harsh for an honest mistake, which happened right in the midst of 3 other flags and genuine reviews. =/

Comment: AFAIK there are no shorter bans; also it's not like you can't participate on SO anymore because you're review banned for a week. And if you thought that an answer like that one was acceptable and needed no action _regardless of the spam link_, then I think it's entirely justified you take a timeout and reevaluate the quality standards SO expects from questions and answers.

Comment: @leigero: spam is a serious matter. The ban worked, it got your attention and you came here to learn about what you missed and how to avoid it in future, didn't it? 7 days is not long at all, it'll be over before you know it.

Comment: @leigero If it helps, stop thinking about this as punishment but as an excellent opportunity to focus your energy elsewhere, even if only for a week.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So, just to check, what exactly constitutes spam? What if it turned out that this software was actually a legitimate tool to accomplish this task? Is it considered spam to endorse any product?

Comment: @leigero: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior; posts should answer the question. If an external resource helps with that, then you can link, but you should disclose your affiliation (including 'not my product, but it helped me) and it shouldn't be the only thing you post about. So for this link, where there was no affiliation disclosed, I'd check the account for other posts at the very least. This is apart from the question being off-topic.

Comment: @l4mpi: there are shorter bans.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was the one who banned you from review, after seeing this:

[image]

You and three others voted "No Action Needed" on posts by this spam ring, allowing their advertising to make it through review and exist on the site. Thankfully, several other reviewers flagged these as spam so that we were able to catch them and deal with the group afterward. Still, two of these posts had lasted for a week on the site because of reviews like this.

Your ban from review was the shortest I handed out, because everyone else who approved this had been banned multiple times before. You'd been banned before this for 2 days for failing audits, so I escalated this to 7 days to make sure you paid attention this time. Approving spam is about the worst thing you can do in review, so we take this very seriously.

When in the First Posts or Late Answers review queues, your first priority is making sure spam, trolling, and non-answers don't get approved. This was a post by a brand-new user, speaking glowingly about a commercial product, with a link to said product. Even if you're not sure about using a full spam flag, use a custom flag for this and explain what you saw. "No Action Needed" is not an appropriate response to a post like this, and can cause harm to the site by allowing spam through.

Comment: If you wanted to make an argument as to why that post is not obvious spam, you could say that it looks like it does exactly what the OP asked for:   Posted tools that supposedly converted MP3 to ACC and FLAC to ACC

Comment: @SamIam: It's still obviously wrong to mark it "No Action Needed", because non-programming answers are always unwelcome.

Comment: @BenVoigt does that mean I ought to go flag and downvote the accepted answer on that question?

Comment: @SamIam: It means you should go vote to delete the question, it's asking for answers that break the rules.  Or edit it to make it ask for solutions in .NET (tags and title suggest this, but the question body is awful).  But that wouldn't rescue it; asking for library recommendations is off-topic also.  You may also, at your option, downvote the answer.

Comment: @SamIam: Please note that the accepted answer is both a programmer's library and a set of executables, basically samples for the library, that are useful at the command-line in their own right.  It's still low-quality; a link to a library of some hundreds of thousands of lines of code without any additional direction has minimal utility.